# What were those "mud-pots" for in S01E01?

Tags: plot-explanation, peaky-blinders

In the first episode of [Peaky Blinders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peaky_Blinders_%28TV_series%29) you find a scene where Grace Burgess personally applies for the job in the local bar/pub.

After discussing a bit with the owner whether she'll fit into this job or not, she starts to take up and empty pots from the floor into a bucket. The pots contain some 'mud-like' liquid. What was that and what was it good for? Did the bar visitors spit inside those pots, did they maybe urinate or puke inside?

Answer (score 15):

They're '[Spittoons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spittoon)'.

> The Garrison Tavern has ended up as a cross between an American speakeasy and a spit and sawdust British boozer. There is sawdust on the floor. As for the spit, a special recipe has been used to fill the metal spittoons at the foot of the bar, into which tobacco-chewing regulars would discharge.

[BBC Source](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-23761594)

Answer (score 1):

They are called spittoons and, as the name suggests, they are indeed for spit.

The reason the consistency could be 'mud-like' could be a combination of spit and alcohol being poured in throughout the night or when the barmaid clears the tables.

Comment: I suspect the tobacco would be a more significant part of the spittoons being mud-like.

Comment: Actually its not unknown for less scrupulous landlords to recycle beer from drip drays and partially filled glasses - and pour it back into the barrel

Answer (score -2):

The buckets contained what was/is known as "tobacco juice" from those who would chew or dip whilst at the bar.